# SwiftUI: Create a view like List but with different layout

Tags: listview, memory-leaks, swiftui

*Edit with some codes that can be used to reproduce the issue. (My real app will have thousands of items in the items list.*

I am working on a small app which uses SwiftUI. I have a view that depends on data to redraw some elements, for example,

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyItem: Identifiable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
    var yearsOfUse: Double
}

struct MyView: View {
    @Binding var aListOfItems: [MyItem]
    var body: some View {
            VStack(){
                ForEach(aListOfItems){item in
                    Text(item.name)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var items: [[MyItem]]
    @State var currentList: [MyItem]
    @State var currentListIndex: Int

    var body: some View {
        VStack(){
            Button(action: {
                if self.currentListIndex < self.items.count {
                    self.currentListIndex += 1
                    self.currentList = self.items[self.currentListIndex]
                }
            }){
                Text("Next")
            }.disabled(self.currentListIndex >= self.items.count - 1)
            Spacer()
            MyView(aListOfItems: $currentList)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var items : [[MyItem]] = [[MyItem(name:"Pen", yearsOfUse:0.5), MyItem(name:"Pencil", yearsOfUse:1.0)],
                                     [MyItem(name:"CopyPaper", yearsOfUse:0.5), MyItem(name:"Pencil", yearsOfUse:1.0), MyItem(name:"BallPen", yearsOfUse:1.0)],
                                     [MyItem(name:"Pen", yearsOfUse:0.5), MyItem(name:"Rubbers", yearsOfUse:1.0)],
                                     [MyItem(name:"Pen", yearsOfUse:0.5), MyItem(name:"Siccer", yearsOfUse:2.0), MyItem(name:"Pencil", yearsOfUse:1.0)],
                                     [MyItem(name:"Pen", yearsOfUse:0.5), MyItem(name:"Pencil", yearsOfUse:1.0)]]

    static var currentItem = items[0]
    static var currentIndex = 0
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(items: items, currentList: currentItem, currentListIndex: currentIndex)
    }
}

func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).

        // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
        let items : [[MyItem]] = [[MyItem(name:"Pen", yearsOfUse:0.5), MyItem(name:"Pencil", yearsOfUse:1.0)],
                                         [MyItem(name:"CopyPaper", yearsOfUse:0.5), MyItem(name:"Pencil", yearsOfUse:1.0), MyItem(name:"BallPen", yearsOfUse:1.0)],
                                         [MyItem(name:"Pen", yearsOfUse:0.5), MyItem(name:"Rubbers", yearsOfUse:1.0)],
                                         [MyItem(name:"Pen", yearsOfUse:0.5), MyItem(name:"Siccer", yearsOfUse:2.0), MyItem(name:"Pencil", yearsOfUse:1.0)],
                                         [MyItem(name:"Pen", yearsOfUse:0.5), MyItem(name:"Pencil", yearsOfUse:1.0)],
                                        [MyItem(name:"CopyPaper", yearsOfUse:0.5), MyItem(name:"Pencil", yearsOfUse:1.0), MyItem(name:"BallPen", yearsOfUse:1.0)],
                                        [MyItem(name:"Pen2", yearsOfUse:0.5), MyItem(name:"Rubbers", yearsOfUse:1.0)],
                                        [MyItem(name:"Pen3", yearsOfUse:0.5), MyItem(name:"Siccer1", yearsOfUse:2.0), MyItem(name:"Pencil", yearsOfUse:1.0)],
                                        [MyItem(name:"Pen", yearsOfUse:0.5), MyItem(name:"Pencil2", yearsOfUse:1.0)],
                                        [MyItem(name:"Pen", yearsOfUse:0.5), MyItem(name:"Siccer", yearsOfUse:2.0), MyItem(name:"Pencil", yearsOfUse:1.0)],
                                        [MyItem(name:"Pen", yearsOfUse:0.5), MyItem(name:"Pencil", yearsOfUse:1.0)],
                                        [MyItem(name:"CopyPaper", yearsOfUse:0.5), MyItem(name:"Pencil", yearsOfUse:1.0), MyItem(name:"BallPen", yearsOfUse:1.0)],
                                        [MyItem(name:"Pen2", yearsOfUse:0.5), MyItem(name:"Rubbers", yearsOfUse:1.0)],
                                        [MyItem(name:"Pen3", yearsOfUse:0.5), MyItem(name:"Siccer1", yearsOfUse:2.0), MyItem(name:"Pencil", yearsOfUse:1.0)],
                                        [MyItem(name:"Pen", yearsOfUse:0.5), MyItem(name:"Pencil2", yearsOfUse:1.0)]]

        let currentItem = items[0]
        let currentIndex = 0
        let contentView = ContentView(items: items, currentList: currentItem, currentListIndex: currentIndex)

        // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
```

MyView is the view that embedded in the Content View, and every time I click a button on content View, it changes the value of aListOfItem which may contain various of element. For example, the first time I click, aListOfItem contains 5 element, and the second time it contains 7 element. When I tested in the simulator, I found every time it creates new Text view based on the element count. therefore the memory keep increased.

I would like to implement this like List view which enable to reuse the Text view that created before as I know the maximal count of elements in aListOfItem is 12.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Would you provide full code that demo's the problem, for testing purpose? `Text` should not be the reason.

Comment: I agree that Text is not the reason, but I think it happens on ForEach(aListOfItems) as the  count of aListOfItems keep changing. I will try to post the whole codes when I get back home as my current Mac running on 10.14.

Comment: Apparently this should be doable with List. However please share the code

Comment: As I need a special layout which put each text on a circle, I don't know whether List can provide this feature. I used GeometryReader to layout the different items on a circle edge

Comment: @younky you can use `.clipShape(Circle())` on Text() to make it shape of a circle

Comment: @lshmeet, thanks for the tips. I mean to layout the different Text on a circle, for example, if the count of aListOfItems is 12, I would like all these 12 Text view just positioned on the circle's edge in MyView.